# Mac OS X: How to silently start a "Command Line Tool" type of application

Tags: macos, command-line

Using Xcode 4.6, I created a "Command Line Tool" application (let's call this toolA).
In that application, I want to execute another "Command Line Tool" application (toolB).
I use the system() function like below:

```
system("open \"/usr/bin/toolB\"");
```

It works well except that it brings up a Terminal window when executing toolB.
How can I hide the Terminal window or use another way to invoke toolB so it won't show the Terminal window at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
system('command &');
```

`&` puts a process into the background.

Next time spend a few  seconds [Googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+system+silent) (second result).